# MongoDB $sum of array item

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am giving MongoDB a shot and building a simple journal with MongoDB and PYTHON. I have this simple structure :

```
db.posts.findOne()
{
"waketime": ISODate("2016-03-18T11:20:00Z"),
"bedtime": ISODate("2016-03-18T22:00:00Z"),
"day": "day entry",
"dream": "dream entry",
"workout" : [{"type":"cardio"},{"time":45}],
"meditation" : [{"time":10},{"time":10}],
"sex": "none"
}
```

I am trying to get the time I spent working out and the time  I spent working out per type of workout. For the last I have gotten to this :

```
cursor = db.posts.aggregate([
    {"$group": {"_id" : "$workout.type", "count": {"$sum": "$workout.time"}}}
])
```

it returns this :

```
{u'count': 0, u'_id': [u'cardio']}
{u'count': 0, u'_id': [u'strength']}
```

it seems to have grouped correctly on workout.type but it doesn't $sum workout.time

anyone can help me?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the field `workout` is a list of documents. Your error is that you're treating this field as a subdocument. You will be able to solve your problem changing the data model and keep your aggregation as it is. So, try the following model instead:

```
db.posts.findOne()
{
"waketime": ISODate("2016-03-18T11:20:00Z"),
"bedtime": ISODate("2016-03-18T22:00:00Z"),
"day": "day entry",
"dream": "dream entry",
"workout" : {
    "type":"cardio",
    "time":45
},
"meditation" : {
    "type":"dunno",
    "time":10
},
"sex": "none"
}
```

**EDIT:**

> okay but what if i have multiple workouts a day ?

Good point. Let's say that my answer above solves the problem in a bad way because I'm adding the limitation of doing only one workout per day. Let's go back to your something like your model where this limitation doesn't exist. **I've needed to amend it anyway in order to make all the items in the lists equivalent**

```
db.posts.findOne()
{
"waketime": ISODate("2016-03-18T11:20:00Z"),
"bedtime": ISODate("2016-03-18T22:00:00Z"),
"day": "day entry",
"dream": "dream entry",
"workout" : [{"type":"cardio", "time":45},{"type": "strength", "time":45}],
"meditation" : [{"time":10},{"time":10}],
"sex": "none"
}
```

For this example you can use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) as one of the steps in your aggregation pipeline:

```
db.posts.aggregate([{$unwind:{"$workout"}},{$group:{_id:"$workout.type", count:{$sum:"$workout.time"}}}])
```

I haven't tested it, but I hope it works.

Regards

Comment: okay I see now I had a little error in my datamodel. thanks for showing how to use the $unwind ist seems to be working now.